# How to make a "barrel" shape from a flat image (?)

Tags: gimp, inkscape, skew

If you have a flat image ie logo you want glue onto a cylindrical "package" to show final product -- **what free s/w package (or script) do you use?**

(I use inkscape and gimp to create flat art with no real knowledge of 3D editing except perspective in gimp)

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting from an image, and you must insert the label, I suggest you to use the GIMP.

**A. Suggested method with the GIMP**

A very simple way to "glue" your label onto a cylindrical package is shown here (not my work):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THLTFDt8uuw

**B. Have some fun with the GIMP**

Alternatively, you can generate the cylinder using the GIMP's built-in [Map Object](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-map-object.html) plug-in, which provides a way to project an image on a cylindrical surface.

The start image will be mapped on the lateral surface of the cylinder, and I've seen that is better start from a square image (either, you need to resize the resulting image), for example:

[image: start image]

If you need to show the top or the bottom of the cylinder, you should also provide something like this:

[image: top image]

Now, you can invoke the filter: **Filter -> Map -> Map Object...**

[image: the filter]

The filter has some options:

[image: filter options]

The final image:

[image: final image]

You can also start with an image with an alpha background:

[image: final image alpha]

So... have fun with the GIMP!

[image: have fun!]

**C. Alternatives with the GIMP**

There are obviously a lot of alternatives, like the [Panorama Tools Plugins](http://wiki.panotools.org/Gimp). It could be a little tricky to use, but is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I bet this could be beaten in Blender, but if you're looking for something that's relatively easy to do:

1. Download Sketch-up if you don't have it already http://www.sketchup.com/
2. Create a circle of whatever radius you want.
3. Use the Push/Pull tool to make it a cylinder. Again, measure the height to what you want.
4. Click on the "fill" tool.
5. At the top right hand corner, there should be a button that says "create material" when you hover over it.
6. Upload your image for the texture. Set the texture height to the height of the cylinder. Your image width will need to be exact or really close to the circumference of your cylinder or it will overlap/cutoff (it won't stretch the image for you). Lastly, set the image opacity to 100. Click on the curved edge of the cylinder, and tada, curved image on a can which you can rotate, pan, zoom in on, and zoom out on.

Time taken: about 3 minutes.